# Can I access the content of an iframe in JavaScript that is part of a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an iframe within the main window named "test_iframe". I want to access the content of "test_iframe" within a [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) extension. I understand that I can do this if I have requisite permissions given in `manifest.json`.

Can I access the content of this iframe from a background HTML page? Or can I access it in a content script which is part of that extension? (In the latter case I suppose I have to pass the iframe content from the content script to a background page as part of a message for further processing(?))

Comment: Is this just for your own personal use? If so, you could disable the same-origin policy by running chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag. Otherwise you have to send messages back and forth between the windows using the extension API; it's kind of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this `test_iframe` comes from `http://frame.example.com`. I would just inject a content script directly to `frame.example.com` (instead of the parent page) and do everything there.

Comment: @serg- I am trying to submit data to 10 different 3rd party sites at a time- the response for each of the 10 submissions will be opened in diff. iframes- now i want to get the data of all 10 iframes and send this to my app through xmlhttprequest. I want to inject a script into the main window (which contains the 10 iframes) and that script should obtain contents of all 10 iframes- can i do it this way? What other way do you suggest? Thanks...

Comment: @user893664 I am pretty sure you cannot access iframe content from parent page if they are on different domains.

Comment: @serg- i thought that if permissions were available in manifest.json, then you can access any content?? Only this content can be accessed only by content script or background page only?

Comment: @user893664 manifest permissions affect only ajax requests as far as I know.

Comment: @serg- this is what is given in the developer guide of chrome extensions, on topic "Permission=match pattern"- Specifies a host permission. Required if the extension wants to interact with the code running on pages. Many extension capabilities, such as cross-origin XMLHttpRequests, programmatically injected content scripts, and the cookies API require host permissions. For details on the syntax, see Match Patterns. --- Note that "programmmatically injected content scripts" are also mentioned here, so i feel that this means that a script can access content of an iframe, however I may be wrong.

Comment: The iframe domain must be in your permissions block in the manifest. That will allow you to inject code and manipulate the iframe from within. You will need to use setTimeOut() to wait for iframe to complete loading before attempting to access the content of the ifram.